# MySQL Selecting Dates Within Number of Days

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL table similar to this:

```
item  |  order  |  start date  |  end date
------------------------------------------
  1        1       2015-09-15    2015-09-20
  2        1       2015-09-15    2015-09-20
  1        2       2015-09-20    2015-09-25
  2        2       2015-09-20    2015-09-25
```

What I want to do is execute a query that will check if any end-dates are within 7 days of a future start date, and return the result.  Does anyone know how this could be done?

EDIT:  Should be more specific I suppose - the start date and end date of an order (say in this case order 2 from the example table) can be within 7 days of each other.  I want to check if order 1's end date is within 7 days of order 2's start date.  Sorry if that wasn't clear before.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `datediff` function.

```
select * from table_name
where 
start_date > curdate()
and datediff(end_date,start_date) between 0 and 7
```

Comment: Won't that return a positive for `order 2` in my example table?

Comment: Yes you should get the last 2 rows from the given example.

Comment: But does that give a positive even if order 1's end date was not within order 2's start date since order 2 has a start date and end date within 7 days of each other?

Comment: So you mean the check should be done on similar orders where the start date of the 2nd order is within 7 days of order 1's end date ? and if so is there a primary key in the table to define which one is the first order or which one is 2nd order ?

Comment: I mean to say - I want to check if order 1's end date is 7 days within order 2's start date, but I don't want to include if order 2's start and end dates are within 7 days of each other.  I only want to see if order 1's end date is within 7 days of order 2's start date.  Sorry if that wasn't clear before.  EDIT:  Should add that this should scale to 100s of orders.

Comment: Yes this could be done using user defined variable to do the calculation in mysql which is kind of complex. This also would require some key to define which order is first and which is 2nd (primary key auto-incremented is the best). Also you have outlined only 4 rows, there could be many combination of data, so it would be good if you provide some more sample data and expected result into the question and of course without primary key to see which one is first or 2nd is nearly impossible since mysql data is un-ordered unless some column defines the order EX: primary key.

Comment: Hrm ok...I am using PHP...maybe I could add 7 days to the end date and then do a < and > comparison instead?  I think I may try that route since it would be much simpler.  I will still mark your answer as the right one for using `datediff` since that is essentially correct...just isn't complete for my specific scenario.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Yes its better to handle them in application level since as I said before those calculations are bit complex in mysql level using user defined variable and if you do not know how to use them it will look like alien language :)